# Is it possible to convert MS Visio drawings back to VBA code?

Tags: vba, visio

I have tried to generate a Visio drawing using VBA coding. Then, if I would like to modify my drawing (eg. changing the length or width of blocks) and after modification, is it possible to generate the latest VBA coding based on the modified drawing? For example:

```
Sub par1()
Dim vsoSelection As Visio.Selection
Set vsoSelection = ActiveWindow.Selection
Dim vsoShapepar11 As Visio.Shape
Set vsoShapepar11 = ActivePage.DrawRectangle(1, 2, 2, 1)
vsoShapepar11.Text = "par1"
vsoShapepar11.Cells("Char.Size").Formula = "= 30 pt."
vsoShapepar11.Cells("Fillforegnd").Formula = "RGB(210,12,66)"
vsoShapepar11.BringToFront
End Sub
```

With this code, I am able to generate a block:

[image: initial drawing]

After I modified, the block is like this:

[image: modified drawing]

Am I able to convert the modified drawing back to VBA coding? Thank you.

Comment: No, you cannot create code from a Visio drawing like that.

Comment: Might help to post a simple example of your VBA to create the drawing.

Comment: I have added the examples inside. Hope it will help to clarify the question. Thanks ya

Comment: If your question is how can you change existing shapes then you can [loop through shapes on a page](https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/11/looping-through.html).  You then need some way of uniquely identifying the shapes.  If the text you're applying ('par1') is unique then that may be one option, otherwise you could add a User cell.  If you really mean can you generate VBA code, then I suppose in theory, yes, but it would be helpful to understand what your use case is.